# chkrootkit on cron but report only if it detects a positive (false or not)

Tags: cron

I would like to create a cron job that runs chkrootkit, but only emails me the resulting log if there is a positive, false or not. The chkrootkit faq gives this as a suggestion:

```
0 3 * * * (cd /path/to/chkrootkit; ./chkrootkit 2>&1 | mail -s "chkrootkit output" root)
```

...but I run an HPC cluster with over 100 nodes. I only want it to mail the log if it has detected something to which I should pay attention.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [README](http://www.chkrootkit.org/README):

> 7. Output Messages
>
>    ---
>
>    The following messages are printed by chkrootkit (except with the `-x`
>      and `-q` command options) during its tests:
>
>    "`INFECTED`": the test has identified a command probably modified by
>      a known rootkit;
>      ...

So write  little script that runs `chkrootkit` and redirects the output to a temp file, parse the temp file for the string  "`INFECTED`" and if found; send an email with the relevant info to identify the host and add that temp file as an attachment, delete temp file.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking along the same lines but wanted to verify I was on the right track. :)